# PHP - Why can't I access data from the second element of a multidimensional array/

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, syntax, multidimensional-array

I couldn't find any useful examples or help online via google search, and the solution should be simple, but the results are not what I'm expecting.

I have 3 arrays - to list a few:

```
$A = array(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1);
$B = array(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1);
$C = array(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1);
```

And then I wanted to create an array where the elements would be `[0]`-`[2]` referencing each of the 3 arrays mentioned above.  The declaration for that is:

```
$LETTERS= array($A,$B,$C);
```

I'm trying to get the elements of `$A[x]` with this code:

```
$LETTERS[0][0];
```

But the problem is that it outputs: `Array[0]` instead of `1`

If I echo `$A[0]` the output will be `1` as expected.

So what am I doing wrong?  I don't think there is a problem with reserved words &| using uppercase letters as variables, is there?

How can I access data in this 2-dimensional array?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**EDIT**
The problem was that I was trying to echo the output with this code:

```
echo "element [0][0]: $LETTERS[0][0]";
```

For some reason, this wont work.  I needed to keep out everything except the actual variable.  Anyone know why that's the case?

Comment: No it doesn't http://codepad.org/p3Vk0FFp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-check your code.

```
echo $LETTERS[0][0];
```

outputs 1

edited question answer

```
echo "element [0][0]: {$LETTERS[0][0]}";
```

Answer (score 3):

Works here:

```
php > $A = array(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1);                                        
php > $B = array(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1);
php > $C = array(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1);
php > $LETTERS= array($A,$B,$C);
php > echo $LETTERS[0][0];
1
```

ok, given your edit... PHP's interpreter isn't greedy. It will not pull in multiple array dimensions when you embed that multidimensional array in a string. e.g

```
echo "$arr[0][0]"
```

is seen as

```
echo "$arr[0]", "[0]"
      ^^^^--arrray
                 ^^^-random string
```

Doing `echo $array` forces the array into string context, but PHP will not dump the array's contents, it will simply print out `Array`, which is why you got `Array[0]`.

To force PHP to see the entire array reference, you need to use the `{}` notation:

```
echo "{$arr[0][0]}";
```

which will properly handle the extra array dimensions.

Incidentally, this is also useful for objects-in-strings, e.g.

```
echo "$obj->attribute->attribute"
```

is better written as

```
echo "{$obj->attribute->attribute}"
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is working correctly. Live demo [here](http://codepad.org/GAaHplEy).

**EDIT**: After your edition, the correct way to do that would be:

`echo "element [0][0]: {$LETTERS[0][0]}";`

That way PHP will expand your variable properly.

Comment: Yes, you need to use "{$LETTERS[0][0]}", that way PHP will properly expand your variable.